# Query Firebase for Custom Adapter ListView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

`enter code here`i new in Firebase and i dont understand documentation. I have problems to generate two query's to populate my listView(I use Firebase ui Adapter)

1) I just need to show in the list view , the object that has the same ID of var String(Example 1 in Imange)-KDiXYVxIx_ni5MyKJ1Z

2) I just need to show in the list view , all objects that have the same child email, that I need(Example 2 in Imange)

Is that posible?

[Firebase dashboard Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1JhT.png)

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: In addition: show what you've already tried.